# Resolver expressões matemáticas em java usando string

Tags: java, string

Nao consigo fazer esse código resolver as expressões contidas no banco de dados. No banco, as expressões sao assim:

Todas as expressões cadastradas no banco seguem o padrão descrito abaixo:

```
$expressao = "$x$op1$y$op2$z$op3$w$op4$k";
```

Onde:

```
$operadores = array('+', '*', '/', '-');
$op1 = $operadores[rand(0,3)];
$op2 = $operadores[rand(0,3)];
$op3 = $operadores[rand(0,3)];
$op4 = $operadores[rand(0,3)];
$x = rand(1111111111,9999999999).rand(1111111111,9999999999).rand(1111111111,9999999999);
$y = rand(1111111111,9999999999).rand(1111111111,9999999999).rand(1111111111,9999999999);
$z = rand(1111111111,9999999999).rand(1111111111,9999999999).rand(1111111111,9999999999);
$w = rand(1111111111,9999999999).rand(1111111111,9999999999).rand(1111111111,9999999999);
$k = rand(1111111111,9999999999).rand(1111111111,9999999999).rand(1111111111,9999999999);
```

Exemplo:

```
136745704413540771491283768999*132288955513943880221144001435+131540870513
718749541202397273/136652154113069665481264184389/126364152611910743531217
601923


public class SD {
    static double res;
    static int id ;

    public SD() {
    }
    public static Connection con = null;

    public static void Conectar() {
        System.out.println("Conectando ao banco...");
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/basedados", "root", "pass");
            System.out.println("Conectado.");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("Classe não encontrada, adicione o driver nas bibliotecas.");
           Logger.getLogger(SD.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (SQLException erro) {
            System.out.println("Erro: " + erro);
            throw new RuntimeException(erro);
        }
    }

    public String Retirar() {
        Conectar();

        String nome = "Fillipe";
        String expressao = null;
        List<String> x = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("{call retira_exp(?)}");
            ps.setString(1, nome);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

            while (rs.next()) {
               x.add(rs.getString(2));
               id = Integer.parseInt(rs.getString(1));

            }
           // for (String exp : x) {
           // }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Erro: " + e);
        }
        expressao = x.get(0);


        return expressao;

    }


       public static double Calcular() {
        SD obj = new SD();
        String expr = obj.Retirar();
        System.out.println("Expressao: " + expr);

       // double a = Double.parseDouble(expr);

        String [] valores = expr.split("\\+|\\-|\\*/|\\-");
        String [] op = expr.split("\\d+");
        // op[1] = primeiro operador
        if(op[1].equals("+")){
            //resultado = valor[i] + valor[i+1]
        }


        return res;
    }

    public void EntregaResultado() {

        Double result = Calcular();
        System.out.println("Resultado: " + result);
        try {
            PreparedStatement pstm = con.prepareStatement("{call entrega_res(?,?)}");
            pstm.setInt(1, id);
            pstm.setDouble(2, result);
            pstm.executeUpdate();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Erro: " + e);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       // SD.Conectar();
        SD sd = new SD();
        sd.EntregaResultado();

    }

}
```

Comment: Qual problema exatamente você está tendo?

Comment: então, eu não estou conseguindo implementar o método  que faz o calculo da expressão que esta contido no banco, esse código pega a expressão , resolve e devolve a resposta , as outras partes eu consegui fazer só essa do calculo que nao sei como começa

Comment: o codigo ta retirando a expressao e devolvendo ao banco, so que sem o resultado da expressao

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu faria um método para calcular recursivamente. Note que você tem que dar prioridade a divisão e multiplicação.

```
public static double CalcularRecursivo(String []valores, String[] operadores) {   
    // o array de valores sempre vai ter um elemento a mais do que o de operadores
    // e o operador i é sempre referente a operacao entre os valores[i] e valores[i + 1]

    // para cada operador em operadores
    //  se o operador[i] for / ou * (eles tem prioridade)
    //      faça a conta usando o valor[i] e valor[i + 1] e guarde o valor
    //          monte uma nova lista de valores e operadores, com o valor novo que calculou e sem o operador que já foi utilizado
    //          retorne CalcularRecursivo(novosValores, novosOperadores)

    // se chegou até aqui é porque não tem mais * e / na expressão
    // para cada operador em operadores
    //  se o operador for + ou - faça a mesma coisa de cima

}
```

Comment: aahh, ok michelle muito obrigado , irei tentar aqui

Comment: Uma dica é criar uma outra classe com public static main e testar só esse método lá, separado desse código todo de banco de dados. Lá você cria umas strings simples pra testar, tipo 8+5*0 e testa pra ver se dá certo, se ele não vai zerar a expressão. Invente alguns casos de teste tipo esse. Vai ser muito mais fácil do que brigar com aqueles números enormes que vem do banco de dados.

Comment: consegui fazer... muito obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: Parabéns, @HudsonRodrigues, sabia que ia conseguir! Você poderia, por gentileza, colocar a sua solução no texto da sua pergunta? Assim outra pessoa no futuro que tiver a mesma dúvida vai poder usá-la.